# From a Quantum Chemistry Point of View how can I break Bonds without Heating?

Tags: bond, quantum-chemistry, magnetism

Is it possible to dissolve/break bonds using strong alternating magnetic fields at high frequency? (Perhaps from tesla coils?) Could you use resonance to cause the bond to weaken over time?  If so how would I calculate or approximate what frequencies those may be?

Basically, how can I liquefy iron without heating it? Could you also apply that to $\ce{SiO2}$?

Comment: Only some things are solid because of *chemical* bonds (I'm excluding inter-molecular forces). Most melting is caused by putting in enough heat to break the bonds *between* molecules not the bonds *inside* molecules. And, even if you could specifically excite some bonds, the energy would usually redistribute across other bonds and other vibrations/rotations in the substance ending up as heat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can (sort of), but there is a catch. As soon as a bond is broken, the very same atoms will throw themselves into each other's arms and form that bond **again**, releasing the extra energy in the form of light and heat. So your method of breaking bonds without heating, whatever it might be, is going to produce *lots of* heat. By applying more power, you may break bonds faster than they are formed and thus liquefy the material, but this would have the side effect of producing even more heat. This is no different from ordinary melting.

Alternating magnetic fields, when intense enough, [would indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction_heating) melt iron and other metals. With $\ce{SiO2}$ we'll have to invent something else.

Comment: So, what do you think the Hutchison effect is doing then ? It seems to have allowed wood to sink inside the metal without burning it.

Comment: [David Copperfield](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_Copperfield_%28illusionist%29) once seemingly made the Statue of Liberty disappear. Hutchison effect is pretty much the same, only on a smaller scale.